# regex - Select everything outside of " and '

Tags: python, regex, quotes, double-quotes

In regex, preferebly in python, how would I select everything outside of " and '?

For example:

```
Text to be selected "text not to be selected" text to be selected 'text not to be selected'
```

So far I have this:

```
.*?(("[.*?]")|('[.*?]')).*?
```

It selects everything inside the quotes and using ?! wont work

Comment: See [demo](https://repl.it/BbHk) which replaces everything contained in quotes with the empty string. It does assume balancing quotes though.

Comment: Yes this works thanks

Comment: @JamesBuck, you'd better make your `.*` non-greedy -- if the string is `keep1 "drop" keep2 "drop" keep3` then you'll only have `keep1  keep3` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

See [demo](https://repl.it/BbHk) which replaces everything contained in quotes with the empty string. It does assume balancing quotes though. – James Buck

```
import re

text = 'Text to be selected "text not to be selected" text to be selected \'text not to be selected\''
remainder = re.sub(r'(["\']).*[^\\]\1\s*', '', text)

print(remainder)
```